OpenLayers 9, distance between lines
The getDistance method of OpenLayers expects two points. I couldn't find a generic method for lines, so I made the following:
import {getDistance} from 'ol/sphere';
export default class Utils{
    static getDistanceBetweenLines(l1,l2){
        let b1=l2.getFirstCoordinate();
        let b2=l2.getLastCoordinate();
        
        let x1=l1.getClosestPoint(b1);
        let x2=l1.getClosestPoint(b2);
        
        let d1= getDistance(x1,b1);
        let d2= getDistance(x2,b2);
        return (d1<d2?d1:d2);
    }
}

I have a feeling I'm doing it wrong. So:
Is there another more "standardized" way of checking distance between (simple) geometries?
Edit: Examples of what I'm looking for.
Assuming LineStrings with 2 vertices each. Circles mark the vertices.

Case 1, compute d



Case 2, d=0 (lines intersect)



Case 3, d=0 (lines touch)



Case 4, compute d



Your algorithm for distance between lines seems strange. Please edit your question with the description of what do you understand as distance between lines, preferably illustrated with some image.

@TomazicM, edited, hope it's clearer now.

Your code sample suggests your are using lon lat coordinates for your geometry.  EPSG:4326 is not a good projection when using getClosestPoint as that method is planar and EPSG:4326 is not a conformal projection (i.e. except at the equator degrees on the x axis do not represent the same distance as degrees on the y axis).  Also your approach would work only for single segment lines which do not cross.

As OpenLayers does not have a built in method for finding the closest points of two geometries it might be better to use a third party utility such as JSTS which will work with any geometry type.  e.g. draw lines on the map https://jsfiddle.net/bg068z4q/ and it will show the nearest points and calculate the distance.

@Mike that's exactly what i'm looking for. Care to post it as an answer so I can accept?

If you use JSTS integration (example in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html) you could find the distance between any of the supported geometry types.  If would be best to use EPSG:3857 or a conformal projection appropriate to the region and optionally pass that to your method:
import {
  LineString,
  MultiLineString,
  MultiPoint,
  MultiPolygon,
  Point,
  Polygon,
} from 'ol/geom';
import {getDistance} from 'ol/sphere';

const parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
parser.inject(
  Point,
  LineString,
  LinearRing,
  Polygon,
  MultiPoint,
  MultiLineString,
  MultiPolygon,
);

function getDistanceBetweenGeometries(g1, g2, projection) {
  const nearest = jsts.operation.distance.DistanceOp.nearestPoints(
    parser.read(g1),
    parser.read(g2),
  ).map((n) => [n.x, n.y]);
  return getLength(new LineString(nearest), {projection});
}

